# onunload of subpage in ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.onunload

I know that there are similar questions here, but i couldn't find any that involve a subpage being closed.

the code has a link, "email1", which opens a subpage, the subpage has a form that is used to update some hidden values on the start page using window.opener, once that subpage is closed, the code checks to see if the values have been changed. if they were, it sends the changes to a different subpage, via ajax, which then formats and sends an email. this works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera, and Microsoft Edge. it does not work in IE11.

```
$(".email1").on('click', function (event) {
 var win1 = window.open("../routing/sub1.php","_blank","height=450,width=510, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
 $(win1).on('unload', function (event){
  if(document.getElementById('hidden1').value != "z"){
   ... 
                 $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '/routing/sub2.php' ,
                            data: { hidden1 : document.getElementById('hidden1').value , 
                                    hidden2 : document.getElementById('hidden2').value , 
                                    hidden4 : document.getElementById('hidden4').value },
                            success: function () {
                            alert("Email has been sent!");
                            }
                        });
   }
  }
 });
});
```

i'm fairly certain that the issue is the unload event. I have tried adding an empty return value to the unload function. I have tried swapping 'unload' with 'beforeunload' . no luck

Comment: Can you try returning a null like `return null;` in your `unload` event handler?

Comment: i assume you mean before the second to last "  });  " , tried that.  did not help. please let me know if you meant somewhere else

Comment: You are correct. However can you place it a line about and check the result?

Comment: not sure what you mean. can you please show the code?

Comment: I meant one block above.

Comment: I have added it to the ajax success fuction, to the IF statement, to the on 'unload' and to the on 'click'. none of those made any difference.

Comment: Hmm.. Looks strange

Comment: i'm not sure what looks strange, but i'm still stuck here if anyone has any other ideas